# How do I stay within the scope of my project when leaving a file in vim?

Tags: vim

I open up a project in Vim.  Lets call it `portfolio`.  I open up the `index.php` but now want to leave that and go to another file, `controller.php`.  I learned that the command `:e.` will take me out but then it may lead me outside the scope of my project.

How do I stay within the scope of my project when leaving a file in vim?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "scope of your project". The `:bn` and `:bp` commands will cycle through buffers, and there is a neat plugin called MiniBufExplorer that's very helpful for visualizing them. Also, vim 7 (I think) has tabs, which give you about the same functionality without a plugin.

Comment: What I mean by the scope of my project is, when I exit the `index.php`  file from my `portfolio` directory, I don't want to go all the way out to my $HOME path.  I want to stay within that directory. Make sense?

Comment: No... you are saying you `cd portfolio` then `vim index.php` and when you `:q` you are no longer in the portfolio directory??

Comment: No I'm saying I `cd portfolio` then `vim index.php` make some changes.  `: w` then want to switch to a different file. I then want to **stay within vim** and navigate outside the file with something similar to `:e.` so I could maybe add another file to the buffer.  As if I were working in Sublime Text, I wanted to open a new file so I click on the file in the tree to the left. (imagine it like this, I don't want to leave sublime text everytime I want to open a new file just like I don't want to in vim either.) Make sense? Hopefully! :)

Comment: Yes, makes sense now. As answered below, `:cd` will switch what vim's working directory is (at first it is the directory where you invoked it). You might like the NerdTree plugin if you don't have it already. :)

Comment: Another tidbit: Once you get proficient with :Explore or NerdTree for project navigation, you may want to look into how vim sessions work. They're great because you can save the state of multiple projects (all buffers, tabs, etc) and easily drop back into that state when you switch projects (or begin your day).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want :e. to show you the files in the same directory as the first file. If that's correct, and if the files are in one directory, use `:cd path-to-your-project-directory`

That will change your working directory to your project directory, and subsequently `:e.` will show the files in that directory.

Note too that once you use `:e.` (or `:Explore :Texplore or :Sexplore`), you can navigate through your directory hierarchy by navigating to subdirectories and pressing enter, or to the `..` entry and pressing enter to move up a directory.

You may also be interested in the NERDTree plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial working directory in vim is the directory you're in when you start vim. If you're in a directory other than your project directory when you start vim, :e will not change your current directory to your project directory when you open a file, so if you just use :e to open different files, you'll have to specify the path each time.

eg: say your project path is /project/foo and you cd to /project and open vim. To open /project/foo/a.txt, you'll have to :e foo/a.txt. If you then want to open file /project/foo/b.txt, you'll have to :e foo/b.txt. :e doesn't change the current working directory in vim. If you cd /project/foo then start vim, you can just do :e a.txt and :e b.txt

You could also do :cd foo from within vim in the scenario above.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would say, just open controller.php with `:sp controller.php` you can then edit both files and switch between then with: `^w k` and `^w j`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with other answers:

- `:e.` provides a listing of the current working directory.
- Plugins such as NERDTree build on this basic idea but also allow you to store bookmarks to commonly visited files and other cool features, [see](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658)
- If you augment this with plugins like bufkill, and tagbar you can actually build up quite a feature rich IDE where you can edit project files within the same context. I put together an installer script you can grab from [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4898)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is the `autochdir` option which changes your working directory to that of the current buffer (so each time you change tabs/windows/buffers it changes the current directory to that of the file being edited). [Link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file#Automatically_change_the_current_directory)

It's not usually recommended because it doesn't play nicely with some plugins.